# Blocking a number in my FastAPI powered Twilio app

Tags: redis, twilio, fastapi, whatsapp

I am trying to create a dynamic list of numbers to block, because my app is using a `Twilio` webhook to route communications to my `FastAPI` backend.

Twilio's FAQ said the following:

### Can I reject or block incoming messages to my WhatsApp number on Twilio?

Currently, it is not possible to block users from sending messages to your Twilio-enabled WhatsApp sender.

WhatsApp is intended to facilitate conversations between end users and businesses, and allow you to seamlessly transition between notifications and customer care.

In the unlikely case that you are receiving a high volume of unwanted messages, or you believe users are sending malicious or abusive traffic to your WhatsApp sender, please let us know by contacting our Support team.

### Technical Workaround

I thought of using a `Redis` cache store, which will allow me to generate this list. However, this doesn't seem sufficient. I should rather have the blocking of numbers on the carrier (Twilio) level, because I am still not mitigating a possible DDOS attack, as my Redis middleware would then be congested, right ?

*Looking for technical/logistical solutions that don't entail involving Twilio.*

Comment: I don't quite understand, you want to block numbers on the Twilio level without involving Twilio? As you've stated, that won't be possible. I would implement this as you've suggested, with a database and a middleware/dependency.

Comment: If you're worried about DDOS attacks,  these can't really be remedied at the Twilio level either, you still have a public facing API endpoint that an attacker can target directly. So, this needs to be protected using e.g. rate limiting, which depending on how you're hosting will usually be done in your cloud provider.

Comment: @M.O. After doing further research I found what I couldn't articulate. What fits my architectural needs is an `API Gateway`. It can act as the front door and prevent my downstream business logic from being congested at the event of a DDOS. Pairing that with a Web Firewall, seems to be industry standard. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, an API gateway could certainly fit your needs.